# jquery onclick function braking after addClass next click

Tags: jquery

Click on the element adds the class `play` the css can handle it well. 
With the next click I would like to remove the class `play` and that just doesn't wants to happen.

What am I doing wrong? Also how could I do better ?

Thank YOU

```
<span class="icon small-player-icons pause" style="display: inline;">click here</span>

$('.small-player-icons.pause').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('play');
});
$('.small-player-icons.pause.play').on('click', function(){
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).removeClass('play');
});

span.small-player-icons.pause {
    background-color:green;
    padding:10px;
}
span.small-player-icons.play {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSHBf/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because on the page load there is no element with class of `'.small-player-icons.pause.play'` in the document, so the query fails silently, you have to delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.small-player-icons.pause.play', function(){
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).removeClass('play');
});
```

But since you are using 2 handlers just for adding/removing classes, why not using `toggleClass()` method?

```
$('.small-player-icons.pause').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('play');
});
```

Comment: that's a good question. I'm not using toggleClass cause I'm calling different functions. If it has this or the other class. Believe that's why and don't think I could handle it with toggleClass only..

Answer (score 1):

A working example:

```
$('.small-player-icons.pause').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('play')){
        alert("clicked");
        $(this).removeClass('play');
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass('play');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbepP/1)

Answer (score 0):

At the time you created your `click` that handles your `.removeClass()` the `play` class does not exists. Try something like:

```
$('.small-player-icons.pause').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('play');
  $('.small-player-icons.pause.play').click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    $(this).removeClass('play');
  });
});
```